# How Can I Print the Number of Associated Products within a configurable product in Magento

Tags: php, magento, printing

I have a bunch of configurable products that all have different numbers of associated products in my magento shop.  On the category pages where it prints price and description, I'd also like to print something like "See All 7 Color Options", 7 being the dynamic value of number of associated products.

I've figured out how to isolate the configurable and associated products, but can't find anything on simply getting the count and printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in list.phtml, in the foreach iteration of products

```
<?php 
$usedProductIds = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
if(count($usedProductIds)>0) {
   echo "Number of products: " . count($usedProductIds);
}
?>
```